# Bridge interfaces with Vlan on Linux based access point

Tags: linux, bridge, vlan

I have a Linux based wireless access point. It has **eth0** interface for ethernet, **ath0** for wireless and **br-wan** as a bridge between the two.

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-wan          8000.001567000041       no              eth0
                                                        ath0
```

**Q:** How can I add vlan tagging on the wireless side so that all the outgoing traffic will be tagged, and only incoming tagged traffic will be accepted?

I'v tried creating a new vlan using **vconfig**

```
vconfig add ath0 15
ip link set ath0.15 up
```

I then used a computer with a traffic generator software to send frames through the Ethernet port of the access point. Using **tcpdump** -e I can see them pass through both ath0 and ath0.15, however no tagging is added whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the ath0.15 device to the bridge:

```
$ vconfig add ath0 15
$ ip link set ath0.15 up
$ brctl addif br-wan ath0.15
$ brctl delif br-wan ath0
```

#### References

- [How to use Ubiquiti radios to do VLAN untagging](https://muehlen.com/ubnt.html)

Comment: I'v tried it, yet it seems that no tagging is beeing done on ath0.15. When checking with tcpdump both ath0 and ath0.15 transmit the same frame.

Comment: @DoctorBurp - have you tried just getting the vlan tagging to work on ath0 first, prior to getting it to work on the br-wan? Just a thought

Comment: @sim - Your thought is right, regardless of working with the bridge, no tagging is done. I will need to check the drivers in depth. Thanks.

Comment: @DoctorBurp - hey did you remember to load the kernel module 8021q? `modprobe 8021q` will do it.

Comment: I do not have it loaded, but I dont think I need to. My access point is openWRT based. When compiling the kernel using ltib I'm selecting 8021q support to be built-in instead of external module.

Comment: @DoctorBurp - OK I just thought of that and wanted to make sure you had that module loaded one way or another. The behavior you're seeing is consistent with the module not being loaded.